# Can't commit. Pre-commit hook failed. Getting: sh: 1: grunt: not found

Tags: jquery, git, npm, webpack, pre-commit-hook

**Problem:**

Every time I try to commit changes I'm getting  previously unseen error.

**Error:**

```
> jquery@3.2.1 precommit /home/usr1/-/-/-/node_modules/jquery
> grunt lint:newer

sh: 1: grunt: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.8.0-56-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "precommit"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! jquery@3.2.1 precommit: `grunt lint:newer`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the jquery@3.2.1 precommit script 'grunt lint:newer'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the jquery package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     grunt lint:newer
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs jquery
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls jquery
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/usr1/practice/web/IgorVit/node_modules/jquery/npm-debug.log

husky - pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

**Descripltion:**

I'm using webpack to bundle project, npm for package management.
Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-react-webpack",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.45",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "firebaseui": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2"
  }
}
```

Project builds without any errors. But after an commit attempt I get previously described error.
Unfortunately, it may be caused by my use of `npm install` in `node_modules/jquery` directory, that used this [package](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json).

I've tried to delete node_modules in my project and to reinstall them through `npm install` but error hadn't changed. What I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it tells you what you're supposed to do: `Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.` If you do, `Tell the author that this fails on your system:[...]`

You are unable to commit because the pre-commit hook that is in place fails. A pre-commit hook is a script that is executed every time you try to commit. If it does not exit successfully, the commit is aborted. The script seems to try to execute `grunt`, but cannot find it. You should make sure it's installed and available.

Comment: `/node_modules/jquery` is added to `.gitignore` file. Whatever I don't understand why pre-commit script handles a directory that even shouldn't appear in commit. Formerly, I hadn't grunt, grunt-cli installed and everything processed without any mentions of grunt. Sorry for molestation.

Comment: Do you even need the hook? As it says, you can `add --no-verify to bypass`. That, of course, will not solve your problem, but at least you'll be able to commit your changes. I'm sorry, but I'm not deep enough in the topic to provide any more help.